# Relative path not detected in node.js

Tags: node.js

I got a http server setup using node.js which responds with an html file in port 3000.This html file has a script tag that returns files using relative path.
Eg html file:

```
<script src="../helloworld.js"></script>
```

Now the request.url in node.js http server callback returns only /helloworld.js instead of ../helloworld.js
Node.js file:

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs')
http.createServer(function(req,res){
if(req.url=='/')
 // read and return html file
else 
{ 
console.log(req.url) // prints /helloworld.js instead of ../helloworld.js
//reading helloworld.js from filesystem
}
}).listen(3000)
```

Comment: There are no relative URLs sent to your server from the browser.  The browser will take `../helloworld.js` and turn it into an absolute path using the path of the current web page to resolve the `../`.  Just look at the network tab of the browser to see exactly what it is sending to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the server side, if the url is rooted, ../ means nothing.

That is:

on the url

```
www.example.com/notroot
```

Using

```
../somefile.js
```

fetches it from

```
www.example.com/somefile.js
```

But if the url is already rooted, ie:

```
www.example.com
```

using

```
../somefile.js
```

will not work, since there is no parent directory to access.

**Also**, you don't need the fs component to fetch files from the client side. This is only used to fetch files from the server side (where ../ WILL work).
But as you used  I assume that this is a DOM tag embedded in the client's browser and not on the server side.

Comment: yes the script tag is in the client side.The fs module is used to retrieve files from the server and send it to the client.

Comment: So do you understand my answer?

Comment: Yes i understood the answer.I have decided to move my node.js file to a parent directory where i can access every other file without using ../